# Finding the pattern of an email by python function

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to make a function that can track the pattern of an email.
The function should take the firstname, lastname and domain and return the pattern for this domain.

So for example Joe Smith at Doodle Inc has the email adress: joe.smith@doodle.com.

The function should return {firstname}.{lastname}. But when the e-mail adress is j.smith@doodle.com it should return {firstname[0]}.{lastname} and so on.

I've already tried something by hardcoding all the different possibilites in a list and return the index of the correct item, but I'm looking for a way to do this smarter.

```
def find_pattern(fname, lname, email):
    pp = [
        fname + "." + lname,
        fname + lname,
        fname[0] + lname,
        fname[0] + "." + lname,
        lname, 
        lname + fname, 
        lname + fname[0],
        lname +  "." + fname[0],
        lname +  "." + fname[0],
        fname + "_" + lname,
        fname[0] + "_" + lname]
    for x in range(len(pp)):
        if email.split("@")[0] == pp[x]:
            return x
```

Comment: You have to decide what kind of separators you're going to take into account, thats all. I believe the only thing you have to hardcode are all of the different kinds of separators, but there's no need of specifying index 0 when you think there's only one letter, since you're not requesting a single character from a larger string, but the character itself is the string.

Comment: It's really not clear what "pattern" you are looking for. You generally can't expect email addresses to have a localpart which reveals the owner's name.

Comment: @tripleee, the pattern I'm looking for is that of the first part of the email adress. Companies use the same patterns to create email adresses for their employees, and if I know that the pattern of company X = firstname.lastname I will also be able to generate an email adress for every employee that I know works there.

Comment: It's still not clear what the input or the expected output is here. Do you mean if you see `"Lastname, First" <firstname.last@outlook.com>` the pattern should tell you that Outlook.com users can be expected to have this ass-backwards Microsoft naming convention, while `firstname.last@gmail.com` should return `gmail.com: firstname.last` (at the risk of false positives for `guess.badly@gmail.com`)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. It doensnt work for personal e-mailadresses ;)